# Regex to remove last / if it exists as the last character in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like a regular expression or otherwise some method to remove the last character in a string if and only if that character is '/'.  How can I do it?

Comment: what language are you using? javascript? php?

Comment: @Jeff - Javascript, its on the tags my friend.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
string = string.replace(/\/$/, "");
```

`$` marks the end of a string. `\/` is a RegExp-escaped `/`. Combining both = *Replace the `/` at the end of a line.*

Answer (score 6):

Just to give an alternative:

```
var str="abc/";
str.substring(0, str.length - +(str.lastIndexOf('/')==str.length-1)); // abc

var str="aabb";
str.substring(0, str.length - +(str.lastIndexOf('/')==str.length-1)); // aabb
```

This plays off the fact the `Number(true) === 1` and `Number(false) === 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = //something;
if(str[str.length-1] === "/") {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "example/";
str = str.replace(/\/$/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = "example/";
t.replace(/\/$/, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not regex but could solve your problem

```
var str = "abc/";

if(str.slice(-1) == "/"){
str = str.slice(0,-1)+ "";
}
```

Comment: Instead of `str.slice(-1) == "/"` it might be cleaner to use `str.endsWith("/")`,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ssn1').keyup(function() {
      var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      val = val.substr(0,9)
      val = val.substr(0,3)+'-'+val.substr(3,2)+'-'+val.substr(5,4)
      val = val.replace('--','').replace(/-$/g,'')
      this.value = val;
});
```