# In Javascript how can I check if a string contains \ (backslash) at the end of it, and if so remove it?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to remove last / if it exists as the last character in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602301/regex-to-remove-last-if-it-exists-as-the-last-character-in-the-string)
>   [Javascript: How to remove characters from end of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597611/javascript-how-to-remove-characters-from-end-of-string)

In Javascript how can I check if a string contains \ (backslash) at the end of it, and if so remove it? Looking for a regex solution.

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Please show more research efforts. Googling for "remove last character of string javascript regex" shows a lot results, including http://stackoverflow.com/q/7602301/427545

Answer (score 4):

```
if (myString.match(/\\$/)) { 
  myString = myString.substring(0, myString.length - 1);
}
```

The Regex '\$' Will match an escaped character '\' followed by the end of line. If this is a match, it runs the `substring` method to get everything but the last character.

As pointed out, in this case this can be simplified to:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\\$/, "");
```

*(Thankyou @Lekensteyn for pointing it out)*

I've left both answers up so one can see the methodology if removing the match is no longer the goal.

Comment: Can be simplified to `string = string.replace(/\\$/, "");`

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest:

```
var string = 'abcd\\';
if (string.charAt(string.length - 1) == '\\'){
    // the \ is the last character, remove it
    string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
}
```

References:

- [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Comment: right but what about the removing that last character if this is true?

Comment: Using the variable name `string` is asking for trouble / confusion with the native `String`.